# Adding a UISearchBar to a UIActionSheet in an iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, uisearchbar, uiactionsheet

I'm having some trouble implementing a design for an app I'm building. The design shows a UIActionSheet menu with a search bar at the top. When someone enters in text into the search bar, the menu goes away and is replaced by a table view containing search results. (The search results display in a similar style to when you slide all the way left on your home screen to search on your iPhone / iPod)

Here's essentially what I'm trying to pull off:

[image]

Here's the code I have:

```
// build menu
UIActionSheet* menu = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                      delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                      destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Button 1",@"Button 2",@"Button 3",nil];

[menu showInView:self.view];

UISearchBar *searcher = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake (0, -216, 320, 44)];
searcher.delegate = self;

// use transparent background  
[[searcher.subviews objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];

[menu addSubview:searcher];
```

When I run this, it is as though the search bar is disabled. You cannot click on it or open up a keyboard. If I change the vertical position of the search bar from -216 to 0, I can click on it and bring up a keyboard, but I'm unable to type anything.

I'm a little confused about how I can implement this. Any ideas? I'm using Xcode 4.4 with ARC and storyboards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how `UIActionSheet` objects work. Do something else instead, like sliding up a `UIView`.

From the Apple iOS Human Interface Guidelines:

> Use an action sheet to:
>
> - Provide alternate ways a task can be completed. An action sheet allows
>   you to provide a range of choices that make sense in the context of
>   the current task, without giving these choices a permanent place in
>   the user interface.
> - Get confirmation before completing a potentially
>   dangerous task. An action sheet prompts users to think about the
>   potentially dangerous effects of the step they’re about to take and
>   gives them some alternatives. This type of communication is
>   particularly important on iOS-based devices because sometimes users
>   tap controls without meaning to.

Comment: I just showed the client that bit from the Human Interface Guidelines and they moved the Search bar to another spot in the app. ;) thanks